# understading the corr heatmap

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, heatmap

I want your help to analyze this correlation heat map
If you look at this heat map, what can you infer and what can you apply?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From this heatmap, you could infer the correlation between features, if they are positively correlated, negatively correlated, or not correlated at all. The intensity of the colors shows the correlation. Dark red, strongly positively correlated, i.e., if the value in one of the features increases, the value of the other feature increases as well. Dark blue indicates a negative correlation, i.e., if a value of one feature increases, the value of the other feature decreases. White refers to no correlation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thx if you apply this to the Randomforest,lgb or xgboost what whould you do? you would find any features to remove or something else?

Comment: @slowmonk based on the problem you have at hand, you decide this. Ideally when you do feature reduction, you end up removing highly correlated features. Do take a look at PCA and tsne for feature reduction. 

You would evalute your model with certain domain knowledge to drop certain features as a permutation combination approach. This could help your model to predict with better accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a feature engineering exercise.  Check the links below for relevant info.

[Feature Selection Techniques in Machine Learning with Python
| Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-techniques-in-machine-learning-with-python-f24e7da3f36e)

[A Feature Selection Tool for Machine Learning in Python
| Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-feature-selection-tool-for-machine-learning-in-python-b64dd23710f0)

And this last one, directly below, is probably the easiest to implement, and probably the best case for your scenario.

http://blog.yhat.com/tutorials/5-Feature-Engineering.html

Comment: The last link is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your features *psfMag_u* and *fiberMag_u* are highly correlated. Remove one of them. Also, *psfMag_u* and *petroMag_u* are negatively correlated. So you can get rid of one of them.

Other than that, nothing much can be deduced just from this graph.